# How to prove tha \mathbb{I}(a,b) - Set of irrational numbers of a segment \left[a, b \right] is measure by Lebesgue?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My proof:
$I = \left[a ,b \right]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, we know that any segment of a real line is measurable and $\mathbb{Q}$ is measurable, Hence $I$ is measurable as the difference of measurable sets.

However, I have doubts about the last conclusion, I know that the sum of measurable sets is measurable, but is this true for the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\setminus B=A\cap B^{c}$. Complements of measurable sets are measurable and intersection of two measurable sets is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Let **A and B** be measurable subsets of real numbers.
Then $A-B = A\cap {B^c}$. Now use the facts that if the sets are measurable then so are their complements and their unions and intersections.